# Saving join attributes through a has_many :through with :conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, data-modeling, relationship, has-many-through

I have an Artist model that looks like this:

```
# app/models/artist.rb
class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Relationships
  has_many  :releases
  has_many  :songs, :through => :releases
  has_many  :featured_songs,  :through => :releases,
                              :class_name => "Song",
                              :source => :song,
                              :conditions => { 'releases.featured', true }                         

end
```

Retrieving the featured_songs works perfectly.  The issue here is I'm unable to add a new featured_song to an artist because for some reason the 'featured' attribute is set to 'nil'.

This is what I'm attempting:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :004 > a = Artist.first
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :005 > a.featured_songs.create(:title => "Title", :user => User.first)
```

The actual result of that is:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :004 > a = Artist.first
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :005 > a.featured_songs.create(:title => "Title", :user => User.first)
  User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` LIMIT 1
  SQL (1.0ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (5.5ms)  INSERT INTO `songs` (`created_at`, `title`, `updated_at`, `user_id`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Thu, 11 Aug 2011 18:30:34 UTC +00:00], ["title", "Title"], ["updated_at", Thu, 11 Aug 2011 18:30:34 UTC +00:00], ["user_id", 1]]
  SQL (1.2ms)  INSERT INTO `releases` (`album_id`, `artist_id`, `created_at`, `featured`, `song_id`, `updated_at`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["album_id", nil], ["artist_id", 1], ["created_at", Thu, 11 Aug 2011 18:30:34 UTC +00:00], ["featured", nil], ["song_id", 6], ["updated_at", Thu, 11 Aug 2011 18:30:34 UTC +00:00]]
   (0.1ms)  COMMIT
```

Notice the:  `["featured", nil]`

Any idea what i'm doing wrong?  How can i properly set attributes on my join without accessing it directly?

thank you!

EDIT: 
To make my issue more clear:

- From an instance of artist i am unable to create new featured songs through the `featured_songs` relationship
- Saves appear to be setting all of the song attributes EXCEPT for (the most important one) `featured`
- The `featured` attribute is being set to `nil` for some reason and this is the real issue here.

Comment: try changin `:conditions` in `has_many` to `:conditions => {  :releases => {:featured => true} }`

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately it did not work.  The result is still `["featured", nil]`

Comment: Thought `has_many` concept would also apply here. Take a look at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many if you haven't, may be you will find something useful.

Comment: FWIW, none of the answers so far have worked for me. :-\

Answer (score 2):

I found the working solution after reading this:

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/5178#issuecomment-4181551

The trick is to create a new first-order has_many association that contains the condition, and then run the has_many :through on *that*.

So, in your case, it would be:

```
class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Relationships
  has_many  :releases
  has_many  :songs, :through => :releases

  has_many  :featured_releases, :class_name => "Release", :conditions => { :featured => true }
  has_many  :featured_songs, :through => :featured_releases, :source => :song
end
```

Comment: methinks it should be 
has_many  :featured_songs, :through => :featured_releases, :source => :song

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Updated :releases_attributes to reflect has_many relationship.

jaydel's answer is along the right lines. This is a problem solved by `accepts_nested_attributes_for`. `has_many` only describes a mechanism to query records, not to update or create them.

The reason the attributes you listed are being updated is because they are part of the song object. The field you're trying to update is the featured field, which is part of your `releases` join table.

`accepts_nested_attributes_for` is the tool to solve the problem of updating nested relationships. If you want to add the featured attribute during creation of a song object (as you do in your example), then you need to add that as part of the nested attributes for the Song class.

```
class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :releases
  has_many :artists, :through => :releases
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :releases
end
```

Your `create` would then look something like this:

```
a.songs.create(:title => 'Title', :user => User.first, :releases_attributes => [{ :id => 123, :featured => true}])
```

Note the addition of _attributes. This is exactly what Rails would do in the views if you were using nested forms. See the ActiveRecord source file [nested_attributes.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/nested_attributes.rb) for proof.

If you really wanted a cleaner way to accomplish this, you could add a `Song#create_featured` method that would merge the `:releases_attributes` hash into the options to `#create`.

Comment: Just to confirm two things: 1- `accepts_nested_attributes_for :releases` should go in the song model only?  In other words, the model im actually using (artist) does not accept nested attributes (seems kind of strange?)  2- i tried the code you provided and get this error:  `NoMethodError: undefined method 'to_i' for :featured:Symbol`

Comment: For #1 - yes. When you take an instance of Artist (your `a` variable) and call `.songs`, you are effectively getting back an `Array` of `Song` objects. Try `a.songs.first.class` and you'll see a song. In actuality, `a.songs` returns an `ActiveRelation` object, but Rails hides that fact from you through the power of ruby (i.e. try `a.songs.class`). Instead of chaining `create`, try chaining the method `build` with just the title and user parameters. Then you can play around in the console and inspect the object before it is saved.

Comment: For #2 - Could you post a stack trace? I might have the plurality of the some of the methods mixed up, or something else might be awry.

Comment: Thinking about it, for #2, I probably gave you the wrong arguments to the :releases_attributes parameter (edited above). It needs to be enclosed in an array because you can add multiple releases in one call. The `id` parameters is only required if you want to update an existing record.

Comment: Yes! thank you.. that got things working/saving!  BUT there's one kind of crazy thing i dont understand -- the `INSERT` is happening two times... check this out: http://pastie.org/private/dsubllg5jxnclvirzdr5g

Comment: The double insert makes sense after thinking about it, actually. One is created implicitly by ActiveRecord to match your new song to your artist, and you are creating a new one through the :releases_attributes parameter. Offhand I don't know of a good way to access the implicit one.

Comment: and again `accepts_nested_attributes_for` can't help here at all.

Answer (score 0):

The key to allow save through association is to provide attr_accessible to fields on association model.

In this case, add line on Release model:

```
attr_accessible :song_id, :feature_id
```