# has_many through and including conditions using _ids helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to use `has_many through` with conditions param in my model but i have a small problem. Let's start with code samples:

#### user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_may  :user_items
  has_many :look_ups, through: :user_items, conditions: { sType: 'SKINTONE' }
end
```

#### user_item.rb

```
class UserItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :look_up
end
```

And now, the problem: i need to use the `look_up_ids` helper to save related lookups but using

```
User.first.look_up_ids = [1,2,3]
```

Is not saving the `sType` field i have defined in my `has_many through` relation (which is `where sType = 'SKINTONE'`). It saves it as nil. Interesting thing is that using `User.first.look_ups.build` works fine and sets `sType` to `SKINCOND`.

Is there any built-in way to tell rails activerecord to autodiscover that field based on association conditions or i need to do that by hand?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13144013/552936 by Craig Walker

> The trick is to create a new first-order has_many association that
>   contains the condition, and then run the has_many :through on that.

So i should use this code:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_may  :user_items, conditions: { sType: 'SKINTONE' }
  has_many :look_ups, through: :user_items
end
```